# Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path in spring-mvc App

Tags: spring-mvc

I have these methods in the spring-mvc controller which are clashing with this URL: http://127.0.0.1:7001/deviceApp/device/en/17624

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://127.0.0.1:7001/deviceApp/device/en/17624':
```

the methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/device/{localeParam}/{itemId}", "/device/{localeParam}/{itemId}/{seoURLapplication}"},  method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    private String showDeviceDetailsAndSeoURLapplication(@PathVariable String itemId,
                                                          @PathVariable String localeParam,
                                                          @PathVariable String seoURLapplication,
                                                          HttpServletResponse response,                                   
                                                          HttpServletRequest request, Model model, Locale locale) {

        Item item = deviceService.getItem   (Long.parseLong(itemId), "P");

        changeLocale (localeParam, request, response);

        addItemToModel (item, locale,  model);

        return DEVICE_DETAIL_VIEW;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/device/{localeParam}/{itemId}", "/device/{localeParam}/{itemId}/"},  method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    private String showDeviceDetails(@PathVariable String itemId,
                                      @PathVariable String localeParam,
                                      @ModelAttribute("searchForm") final SearchForm searchForm,
                                      HttpServletResponse response,                                   
                                      HttpServletRequest request, Model model, Locale locale) {


        Item item = deviceService.getItem   (Long.parseLong(itemId), "P");

        return DEVICE_DETAIL_VIEW;
    }
```

on the web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>deviceWeb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/device</url-pattern>             
        <url-pattern>/device/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/device/*/</url-pattern>         
        <url-pattern>/device/*/*</url-pattern>
       <url-pattern>/device/*/*/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two methods are really ambiguous, according to the path variables you expect in the signature, you should remove the mapping for the `"/device/{localeParam}/{itemId}"` inside the `showDeviceDetailsAndSeoURLapplication`

also, the servlet mapping should either match all request

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>deviceWeb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or,

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>deviceWeb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/device</url-pattern>             
</servlet-mapping>
```

in which case your should remove the `/device` from your controller mapping paths